# Solution to instantly inform the user about the changes occurred on server

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, ape

I'm trying to make an web application that will dynamically inform the user about the dynamic changes occur in server (php/mysql/apache).

I tried to implement a solution through APE (push) server but documentation is poor and the examples are not usable.

Does anyone know a solution that could be implemented to resolve this?

I forgot to add that besause of too many users and they need to constantly check the current status on server AJAX is not best solution.
AJAX was the first choice but we have to replace it.

Comment: You could try web sockets.

Comment: You might be interested in web sockets, e.g. [**Ratchet**](http://socketo.me/).

Comment: Do you mean to check a webserver inside a website? You should have a look to AJAX, which I think is the easiest way. You can perform periodic requests using a Javascript Timer which then calls a PHP script on a server, through AJAX. Then you can have a JavaScript callback running in the background that will collect that response and then act in consequence. Maybe you can use jQuery or any other Javascript framework if you want an easy path.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use AJAX concepts for this purpose.

`jQuery` `AJAX` are very easy to implement with the help of `Javascript` `setInterval()` function.

You can find jQuery AJAX examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax#entry-examples).

All you need to do is write some PHP code which will return response which contains the changes occurred in Server.

In the Javascript layer check the received response and look for the changes. If it has any changes just populate the changes to the user.